# How to fetch current user privileges on table via java in Hive?

Tags: java, hive, privileges

I am trying to connect to Hive Server-2 using Java. My use-case is to verify the user either current user has rights to R/W/Both on a particular table on which  user trying to hit.

Is there any user role or user privileges table available in Hive similar to Relational Database like Oracle, MySQL, etc. ?

If not then how can we fetch user privilege related information on a particular table from Java Code ?

Also I tried to run Grant related query (say `"show grant on table survey"`) from Java but getting Exception *`"Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Sentry does not allow privileges to be granted/revoked to/from: USER"`*